# Adaboost algorithm for multi-class classification

Tags: r, adaboost

What  are the commonly used R packages used to apply adaboost  algorithm for multi-class classification problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adaboost is implemented in the [Adabag package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adabag/adabag.pdf), the [Fast Adaboost package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastAdaboost/fastAdaboost.pdf), the [gbm package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf) and the [JousBoost package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/JOUSBoost/JOUSBoost.pdf).